# Xamarin Studio does not recognize iOS device even though XCode does

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I have a Mac 10.10.5 setup with XCode and Xamarin Studio for iOS development.

After an update Xamarin Studio no longer recognized my iOS device. It turned out that XCode could not start. After launching XCode which installed several components XCode now WORKS, I can build, deploy and debug in XCode. However Xamarin Studio cannot see the device in the device selection box.

Xamarin Studio can see, build for and deploy to any Simulator.

Visual Studio which uses the same machine as a Build Sever can see the device in the device selection box, but will not deploy nor debug (nothing happens).

Everything worked before the Mac / XCode / Xamarin update. No changes to device, project or settings.

Comment: Are you still seeing this behavior after updating to the latest stable releases? 

(https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-ios-9-3-xcode-7-3-support/)

Answer (score 3):

So Xamarin piggy-backs onto Xcode, meaning that as long as Xcode should see it, Xamarin should see it as well. This most likely means that something within Xamarin is causing your device to be filtered out of the deployment targets list. Could your "Deployment Target" within the Info.plist within your project not be set to the proper iOS version?

Comment: The "should" is exactly where I can very annoyed. Xcode worked, Xamarin Studio on the Mac worked, the Visual Studio add-in did not work.

However this is now more than a year old, and it has been resolved during this time by itself, either by Xamarin updates or Xcode update. I am unsure which one.

Comment: D'oh, didn't see the date, actually. Oddly enough, this showed up in my new and unresolved issues for my tags. Sorry for raising the dead, and happy coding!